# Java Serializable object contains non-Serializable fields

Tags: java, serialization

I use FindBugs in eclipse, and there are tons of "troubling" warnings.
Here is the sketch code:

```
public class SerializableObject implements Serializable {

  private NonSerializableObject nso;

  .. setter, getter, everything else

}
```

Can this cause troubles? Or can we just ignore it? Or should we do the Serialization everywhere it touches?

It is in a JSF Web project.

Comment: To downvoters and close suggestions: please leave a comment what do you miss, I am constructive, and since there were a good answer to my question which worked well, I think there are people who understood my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mark them as `transient`

When you declare a field transient it will be ignored during the serialization and deserialization process. Keep in mind that when you deserialize an object with a transient field that field's value will always be it's default (usually null.)

Comment: i see it is pretty new to Java, thanks for the answer! Should I use them like `private transient NonSerializableObject nso;`?